# Entity Framework Core insert data in reference table many-to-many relationship with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So got two tables `Book` and `Category` and then another table names `BookCategory` which has the relationship both of the other tables everything working fine just having an issue when trying to insert data with the reference's table.

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}  

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}  

public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasKey(bc => new { bc.BookId, bc.CategoryId });  
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
        .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);  
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);
}

public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Let suppose I have data in the object `_book` detail about the book and have id's of the category in `_cat` which has reference to it

If I do this it will save all the information of books in the table

```
_context.Add(_book);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But the question is this I want to update the reference table as well with the book and 2 categories which are referencing it.

I can use this but this, not the right way can anyone help me out or share a link of an article which is saving data in tables in one go as you can see I am sure it will give an error because of the bookid is not generated yet thanks

```
var z = new BookCategory();
z.BookId = _contextPosts.dbcontext.book.Where(c => c.Id == item).FirstOrDefault().Id;
z.CategoryId = CategoryId.Id;
z.Book = _contextBook.dbcontext.book.Where(c => c.Id == item).FirstOrDefault();
z.Category= Category;
tag.Post.Add(z);
_context.Add(_book);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but you should be able to do the add with just a book and it's related BookCategory objects -- assuming that the Categories you are trying to add to the book already exist (and you know their IDs).

Create your object and the related BookCategories:

```
var _book = new Book { Title = "My Title", 
                       Author = new Author { whatever }, 
                       BookCategories = new List<BookCategory> {
                          new BookCategory { CategoryId = whateverCatId1 },
                          new BookCategory { CategoryId = whateverCatId2 }
                       }
                     };
 _context.Books.Add(_book);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This should create your book and the associated BookCategory entries with the correct BookId.  EF will create the Book object first, get its ID, and then fill in the BookId in the linking table. The Add method processes the entire graph.

Comment: Thanks @bryan but having issue so implemnted the logic let me show you

Answer (score 1):

```
        var _Tag = new Tag
        {
            Name = tag.Name,

            Post = new List<PostTag> {
                  new PostTag { PostId = 1 },
                  new PostTag { PostId = 2 }
               }
        };

        tag.Post = _Tag.Post;


        _contextTags.dbcontext.Add(tag);
        tag.ModifiyDate = DateTime.Now;
        tag.CretedDate = DateTime.Now;

        await _contextTags.dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Error getting

[image]

[image]

Comment: This code is a bit confusing.  You reference "tag" and you create the variable/object "_Tag".  Where is "tag" coming from, since that is the one you are actually adding?  Is "_contextTags" your DbContext object?